# || converting empty string to bool, && not

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is this normal? Is it a feature or a bug? (I'm using firebug):

```
>>> '' || true
true
>>> '' || false
false
>>> '' && false
""
>>> '' && true
""
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **not** converting the empty string to `Boolean`.

#### With `||`

It is evaluating the left hand side, of which an empty string is *falsy*. It then checks the right hand side (because it's an *or*, and that side *may* be true), and returns that value.

#### With `&&`

Because `&&` needs both sides to be *true* and the left hand side is *falsy*, it doesn't bother checking the right hand side ([short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). Therefore, it just returns the left hand side, which is the empty string.

JavaScript always returns the last value it evaluated.

```
>>> '' || 0 || undefined || null || false || NaN || 'hello'
"hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `||` operator will return the first value which is truthy.

The `&&` operator will return the second value if the first is truthy, otherwise it returns the first.

For more info, you can see the [Logical Operators page on the MDC site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

In your case,

1. `'' || true`; `''` is false, so the `||` operator moves onto the second value, which is true, and so returns it.
2. `'' || false`; `''` is false, so the `||` operator moves onto the second value, which is false, and has no more values to compare, so returns it.
3. `'' && false`; the first value (`''`) is falsy, so it returns it.
4. `'' && true`; the first value (`''`) is falsy, so it returns it.

Comment: Your answer would be more clear if you pointed out that '' is falsy which, I believe, is what is confusing @Paolo.

Comment: @chuckj: I've added that to my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not that one is converting and the other isn't; the lines with `||` are returning their second operand and the lines with `&&` are returning their first, due to short-circuiting.

> `[ECMA-262 11.11]:` **Semantics**
>
> The production `LogicalANDExpression : LogicalANDExpression &&
>   BitwiseORExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LogicalANDExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. If `ToBoolean(lval)` is `false`, **return `lval`**.
> 4. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `BitwiseORExpression`.
> 5. Return `GetValue(rref)`.
>
> The production `LogicalORExpression : LogicalORExpression ||
>   LogicalANDExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LogicalORExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. If `ToBoolean(lval)` is `true`, return `lval`.
> 4. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `LogicalANDExpression`.
> 5. Return **`GetValue(rref)`**.
>
> The `LogicalANDExpressionNoIn` and `LogicalORExpressionNoIn`
>   productions are evaluated in the same manner as the
>   `LogicalANDExpression` and `LogicalORExpression` productions except
>   that the contained `LogicalANDExpressionNoIn`,
>   `BitwiseORExpressionNoIn` and `LogicalORExpressionNoIn` are evaluated
>   instead of the contained `LogicalANDExpression`, `BitwiseORExpression`
>   and `LogicalORExpression`, respectively.
>
> NOTE The value produced by a `&&` or `||` operator is not necessarily
>   of type `Boolean`. The value produced will always be the value of one of
>   the two operand expressions.