# Change jQuery set without producing a new jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I need to replace the only item in a jQuery set, which contains only one element. I receive this jQuery object as an argument to my function. So I can't just do the following:

```
myJQuerySet = myJQuerySet.replaceWith( anotherDomElement );
```

I found that this trick do the job:

```
myJQuerySet[0] = anotherDomElement;
```

But is it correct and safe?

Comment: jQuery does not provide methods to change sets in-place. So whatever you are doing you have to revert to "hacks". Of course you could have a look at the jQuery source code and try to extend jQuery with ways to do so, though it does not mean that it will be more safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering [how jQuery handles DOM elements passed to `jQuery()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L87), this should be fine:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.set = function(element) {
        if(element.nodeType) {
            this.context = this[0] = element;
            this.length = 1;
        }
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Not sure about the consequences if several elements have been selected though. You might also want to check the current length of the jQuery object.

Also interesting in this regard is [`jQuery.merge`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L703) which is often used when new sets are created or elements are added. It is really just copying all numerical properties from one argument to the other and updating the `length` attribute. So what you are doing *seems* to be fine, but will of course break when jQuery changes the internal representation (if they do that at all).

Answer (score 1):

The only time I can see this being a problem is if the jQuery set was empty; the length attribute won't be updated. If you can guarantee that the size will be at least 1, then you're fine.

Otherwise, you might want to do something like this;

```
myJQuerySet[0] = anotherDomElement;
myJQuerySet.length = myJQuerySet.length || 1;
```

Comment: the selector value won't be updated either which is automatically updated when you use normal pushStack methods

Comment: myJQuerySet.length = myJQuerySet.length || 1;   // really?

Comment: @Matt:  Length is an integer and the result of || is boolean...right?  Bit of a hack (IMHO).

Comment: @Steve, you're confused by the short-circuiting nature of the `||` operator. It also returns one of its operands, not always a boolean.

Comment: @SteveWellens: In JavaScript, the `||` operator returns the first "truthy" value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383200/converting-empty-string-to-bool-not/8383218#8383218 for a better explanation.

Comment: All right, thanks for the info/link (...still don't like it).

Answer (score 0):

You've specified that there's exactly one item in this jQuery object.

You've also specified that you have exactly one *element* that you want to put into it.

So what's actually wrong with creating a new jQuery object?

```
$(myElement)
```

It's the simplest degenerate use of the jQuery constructor, and the only reason I can think of not to use it is if you are micro-optimising.  Don't.

Comment: As I said, my function receive this jQuery object as an argument, so assignment to the argument's variable a new reference will not affect the original object.

Comment: so you're specifically trying to mutate the supplied jQuery object?!  You should just make a new one and return it...  That's what jQuery's own functions do.

Comment: Yes, but you are talking about another situation, when I can change code outside of my callback function.

Comment: @Dmitry I can't tell - you haven't explained your use case or given any other plausible reason why you want to mutate an _existing_ jQuery object.

Comment: I don't think that the full explanation of the reasons will change the conditions, stated in the the question. The goal of functions like mine is to make changes on an object (wrapped in jQuery object) before connecting it to DOM and there are read-only properties, which I can change only by replacing the object with a new one.